# how to scroll to selected div after filtering the dropdown search result

Tags: reactjs, search, react-hooks, scroll, dropdown

This is the fucntion for searching car glass film
There are 2 dropdown and 1 search button. The first dropdown is to select the brand of the film, with the options of several brands. Each brand have multiple series of product, and each series have multiple product. And the second dropdown is to select the product with their own series name as label. If user select only the brand and not select the product, then click search, it will show the information of that selected brand. In the pattern of brand's series name, image of the products in that series, and the description of that series. If that brand have multiple series, it will show like, brand1 -> series1 name/ series1 image/ series1 description, series2 name/ series2 image/ series2 description... in this order. BUT, if the user select the second dropdown which is the product in each series, and then click search, it will automatically scroll into that section of the selected product
[image: when first time landing on this page and choose the brand]
[image: and then select the product in each series(the gray one is the series label)]
you don’t need to select the product to make the information to show
[image: the result when click search]

What i want to do is, when select the product and then search, it will automatically scroll to that selected product section
[image: something like this]

this is the whole file of the page

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import useFilmsNew from '../../../../hook/CarGlassFilmSearch/useFilmsNew'
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress'
import ReactSelect from 'react-select'
import classes from '../FilmBrand.module.css'
import carIcon from '../../../../../public/ProductAndService/FilmBrand/carIcon.svg'
import FilmModal from '../FilmModal'
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeCarousel from '../../../../components/Home/HomeCarousel'
import arrow from '../../../../../public/Home/arrow.svg'

function FilmSearch() {
  const { films } = useFilmsNew()
  const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = useState('')

  const [selectedSeries, setSelectedSeries] = useState('')
  const [selectedSeriesName, setSelectedSeriesName] = useState([])
  const [selectedSeriesDesc, setSelectedSeriesDesc] = useState([])
  const [showingProduct, setShowingProduct] = useState<any | []>([])
  const [searchClicked, setSearchClicked] = useState(false)
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [detaila, setDetaila] = useState('')
  const [detailb, setDetailb] = useState('')
  const [detailc, setDetailc] = useState('')
  const [detaild, setDetaild] = useState('')
  const [detaile, setDetaile] = useState('')
  const [detailf, setDetailf] = useState('')
  const selectedSeriesRef = useRef(null)

  const handleBrandChange = (selectedOption: any) => {
    setSelectedBrand(selectedOption?.value || '')
    setSelectedSeries('') // Reset selected series when a new brand is selected
  }

  const handleSeriesChange = (e: any) => {
    setSelectedSeries(e.target.value)
  }

  // !
  const handleSearch = () => {
    setSearchClicked(true)

    if (!selectedBrand) {
      alert('Please select a brand')
      return
    }

    const selectedBrandData = films.find((film: any) => film.brand === selectedBrand)

    // Show all series of the selected brand
    const allSeriesData = selectedBrandData.series
    const allSeriesNames = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.series)
    const allSeriesDescs = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.desc)
    const allSeriesPics = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.product)

    setShowingProduct(allSeriesPics)
    setSelectedSeriesName(allSeriesNames)
    setSelectedSeriesDesc(allSeriesDescs)

    // if (selectedSeries) {
    //   const index = allSeriesNames.indexOf(selectedSeries)
    //   if (index !== -1 && seriesRefs.current[index]) {
    //     window.scrollTo({
    //       top: seriesRefs.current[index].offsetTop,
    //       behavior: 'smooth',
    //     })
    //   }
    // }
  }
  // !
  const handleBrandClick = (selectedBrand: any) => {
    // Set the selected brand
    setSelectedBrand(selectedBrand)

    setSearchClicked(true)

    if (!selectedBrand) {
      alert('Please select a brand')
      return
    }

    const selectedBrandData = films.find((film: any) => film.brand === selectedBrand)

    // Show all series of the selected brand
    const allSeriesData = selectedBrandData.series
    const allSeriesNames = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.series)
    const allSeriesDescs = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.desc)
    const allSeriesPics = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.product)

    setShowingProduct(allSeriesPics)
    setSelectedSeriesName(allSeriesNames)
    setSelectedSeriesDesc(allSeriesDescs)
  }

  // !

  const filteredBrand = films?.find((film: any) => film.brand === selectedBrand)
  const filteredSeries = filteredBrand ? filteredBrand.series : []

  const formatOptionLabel = ({ value, label }: any, { context }: any) => {
    const film = films?.find((film: any) => film.brand === value)
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center  hover:cursor-pointer">
        {context === 'menu' ? <img src={film?.brandpic} alt={value} className="mt-4 h-[80px]" /> : null}
        <p>{label}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

  if (films === null) {
    return (
      <div className="w-full flex justify-center my-28">
        <CircularProgress />
      </div>
    )
  }

  const brandOptions = films?.map((film: any) => ({
    value: film.brand,
    label: film.brand,
  }))

  const customStyles = {
    control: (provided: any) => ({
      ...provided,
      background: 'white',
      display: 'flex',
      borderColor: '#EBEBEB',
      width: '310px',
      height: '44px',
      marginLeft: '22px',
      borderRadius: '40px',
      boxShadow: '0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0.05);',
      '@media screen and (max-width: 1279px)': {
        marginLeft: '0px',
        width: '100%',
      },
    }),
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/* yellow text */}
      <div className="2xl:w-[1300px] xl:w-[1150px] lg:w-[900px] md:w-[590px] w-[360px] mx-auto flex gap-[11px] mt-[70px] items-center">
        <img src={carIcon} />
        <p className={classes.serchFilmYouLike}>
          ค้นหา
          <span>ฟิล์มที่ใช่กับสไตล์ที่ชอบ</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      {/* select */}

      <div className="lg:flex justify-between 2xl:w-[1300px] xl:w-[1150px] lg:w-[900px] md:w-[590px] w-[360px] mx-auto items-center mt-7">
        {/* brand */}
        <div className="xl:flex items-center justify-between ">
          <p className={`${classes.dropdownHeader} mb-2 xl:mb-0`}>ยี่ห้อ</p>
          <ReactSelect
            value={brandOptions.find((option: any) => option.value === selectedBrand)}
            onChange={handleBrandChange}
            options={brandOptions}
            placeholder="เลือกยี่ห้อฟิล์ม"
            formatOptionLabel={formatOptionLabel}
            styles={customStyles}
            isSearchable={false}
          />
        </div>

        {/* series */}
        <div className="xl:flex items-center justify-between mt-6 lg:mt-0">
          <p className={`${classes.dropdownHeader} mb-2 xl:mb-0`}>series</p>
          <select
            className="hover:cursor-pointer border p-2 px-4 rounded-[40px] border-[#EBEBEB] shadow-sm xl:ml-[22px] lg:w-[300px] w-full"
            value={selectedSeries}
            onChange={handleSeriesChange}
          >
            <option value="" className={`${classes.dropdownPlaceholder}`}>
              กรุณาเลือก series
            </option>
            {/* Map through each series of the selected brand */}
            {filteredSeries.map((series: any) => (
              <optgroup key={series.id} label={series.series}>
                {/* Map through each product in the current series */}
                {series.product.map((product: any) => (
                  <option key={product.id} value={product.id}>
                    {`${product.name} - ${product.color}`}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </optgroup>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>

        {/* search */}
        <div
          className="bg-[#3D3C3C] text-white p-2 rounded-[40px] xl:w-[210px] lg:w-[150px] flex justify-center text-[22px] items-center self-end h-11 hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-600 mt-8 xl:mt-0"
          onClick={handleSearch}
        >
          ค้นหา
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Show selected products after search button is clicked */}
      {searchClicked && (
        <div className="2xl:w-[1300px] xl:w-[1150px] lg:w-[900px] md:w-[590px] w-[360px] mx-auto mt-[60px]">
          {selectedSeriesName.map((seriesName, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="mb-[70px] ">
              <p className={`${classes.brandName} text-center`}>{seriesName}</p>
              <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-5 lg:grid-cols-4 grid-cols-2 items-center xl:gap-7 gap-5 gap-x-7 justify-items-center mt-[57px] mb-[57px] ">
                {showingProduct[index].map((product: any) => (
                  <div
                    key={product.id}
                    ref={selectedSeriesRef}
                    id={product.id}
                    className="md:w-[200px] md:h-[270px] h-[260px] hover:cursor-pointer "
                    onClick={() => {
                      setSelectedImage(product.pic)
                      setDetaila(product.a)
                      setDetailb(product.b)
                      setDetailc(product.c)
                      setDetaild(product.d)
                      setDetaile(product.e)
                      setDetailf(product.f)
                    }}
                  >
                    <img
                      src={product.pic}
                      className="aspect-square xl:h-[200px] lg:h-[180px]"
                      onClick={() => console.log(product.id)}
                    />

                    <div className="mt-2 text-[18px]">
                      <p>
                        {product.name} {product.color}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
              <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: selectedSeriesDesc[index] }}
                className={`${classes.brandDesc} mt-[30px]`}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}

      {/* modal */}
      <FilmModal
        open={selectedImage !== null}
        onClose={() => {
          setSelectedImage(null)
        }}
      >
        {/* here */}
        {selectedImage && (
          <div className="rounded-[8px] pb-3 2xl:w-[800px] xl:w-[700px] lg:w-[600px] md:w-[500px]  z-10">
            {/* detail */}
            <img
              src={selectedImage}
              className="aspect-square xl:h-[330px] lg:h-[330px] md:h-[300px] h-[180px]  mx-auto"
            />
            <div className={`${classes.productDetail} flex justify-center gap-32`}>
              <div className="lg:w-[441px] md:w-[400px] w-[340px]">
                <div className="flex pl-2.5 pr-3.5 justify-between items-center h-10">
                  <p>การลดความร้อนจากแสงแดด (TSER)</p>
                  <p>{detaila}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="flex pl-2.5 pr-3.5 justify-between items-center h-10 bg-[#EAEAEA]">
                  <p>การลดความร้อนจากสปอตไลท์</p>
                  <p>{detailb}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="flex pl-2.5 pr-3.5 justify-between items-center h-10">
                  <p>แสงส่องผ่าน(VLT)</p>
                  <p>{detailc}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="flex pl-2.5 pr-3.5 justify-between items-center h-10 bg-[#EAEAEA]">
                  <p>การสะท้อนแสง(VLR)</p>
                  <p>{detaild}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="flex pl-2.5 pr-3.5 justify-between items-center h-10">
                  <p>การลดรังสี UV</p>
                  <p>{detaile}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="flex pl-2.5 pr-3.5 justify-between items-center h-10 bg-[#EAEAEA]">
                  <p>รองรับสัญญาณ ดิจิทัลบูสต์</p>
                  <p>{detailf}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              className={`${classes.button} bg-black hover:bg-gray-500 w-fit rounded py-2 px-9 hover:cursor-pointer mx-auto mt-5`}
            >
              <HashLink to="/servicecenter#form">นัดหมายเข้ารับบริการ</HashLink>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </FilmModal>

      {/* ---------- brand logo before search ----------- */}

      {/* here */}
      {!searchClicked && (
        <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-5 lg:grid-cols-4 grid-cols-2 2xl:w-[1300px] xl:w-[1150px] lg:w-[900px] md:w-[590px] w-[360px] mx-auto mt-[70px] gap-7">
          {films.map((film: any) => (
            <div key={film.id} className="">
              <img
                src={film.brandpic}
                className="hover:cursor-pointer"
                alt={film.brand}
                onClick={() => handleBrandClick(film.brand)}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default FilmSearch
```

this is the handleBrandChange and handleSeriesChange function

```
  const handleBrandChange = (selectedOption: any) => {
    setSelectedBrand(selectedOption?.value || '')
    setSelectedSeries('') // Reset selected series when a new brand is selected
  }

  const handleSeriesChange = (e: any) => {
    setSelectedSeries(e.target.value)
  }
```

and this is the handleSearch

```
  // !
  const handleSearch = () => {
    setSearchClicked(true)

    if (!selectedBrand) {
      alert('Please select a brand')
      return
    }

    const selectedBrandData = films.find((film: any) => film.brand === selectedBrand)

    // Show all series of the selected brand
    const allSeriesData = selectedBrandData.series
    const allSeriesNames = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.series)
    const allSeriesDescs = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.desc)
    const allSeriesPics = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.product)

    setShowingProduct(allSeriesPics)
    setSelectedSeriesName(allSeriesNames)
    setSelectedSeriesDesc(allSeriesDescs)

    // if (selectedSeries) {
    //   const index = allSeriesNames.indexOf(selectedSeries)
    //   if (index !== -1 && seriesRefs.current[index]) {
    //     window.scrollTo({
    //       top: seriesRefs.current[index].offsetTop,
    //       behavior: 'smooth',
    //     })
    //   }
    // }
  }
```

as you can see, I commented the old scroll logic because it doesn’t work

this is the series select dropdown

```
   <div className="xl:flex items-center justify-between mt-6 lg:mt-0">
          <p className={`${classes.dropdownHeader} mb-2 xl:mb-0`}>series</p>
          <select
            className="hover:cursor-pointer border p-2 px-4 rounded-[40px] border-[#EBEBEB] shadow-sm xl:ml-[22px] lg:w-[300px] w-full"
            value={selectedSeries}
            onChange={handleSeriesChange}
          >
            <option value="" className={`${classes.dropdownPlaceholder}`}>
              กรุณาเลือก series
            </option>
            {/* Map through each series of the selected brand */}
            {filteredSeries.map((series: any) => (
              <optgroup key={series.id} label={series.series}>
                {/* Map through each product in the current series */}
                {series.product.map((product: any) => (
                  <option key={product.id} value={product.id}>
                    {`${product.name} - ${product.color}`}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </optgroup>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
```

and this is the search result when select the brand and click search

```
 {searchClicked && (
        <div className="2xl:w-[1300px] xl:w-[1150px] lg:w-[900px] md:w-[590px] w-[360px] mx-auto mt-[60px]">
          {selectedSeriesName.map((seriesName, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="mb-[70px] ">
              <p className={`${classes.brandName} text-center`}>{seriesName}</p>
              <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-5 lg:grid-cols-4 grid-cols-2 items-center xl:gap-7 gap-5 gap-x-7 justify-items-center mt-[57px] mb-[57px] ">
                {showingProduct[index].map((product: any) => (
                  <div
                    key={product.id}
                    ref={selectedSeriesRef}
                    id={product.id}
                    className="md:w-[200px] md:h-[270px] h-[260px] hover:cursor-pointer "
                    onClick={() => {
                      setSelectedImage(product.pic)
                      setDetaila(product.a)
                      setDetailb(product.b)
                      setDetailc(product.c)
                      setDetaild(product.d)
                      setDetaile(product.e)
                      setDetailf(product.f)
                    }}
                  >
                    <img
                      src={product.pic}
                      className="aspect-square xl:h-[200px] lg:h-[180px]"
                      onClick={() => console.log(product.id)}
                    />

                    <div className="mt-2 text-[18px]">
                      <p>
                        {product.name} {product.color}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
              <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: selectedSeriesDesc[index] }}
                className={`${classes.brandDesc} mt-[30px]`}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
```

I have try to use useRef in the old version of this code. It navigate to the selected product, but it doesn’t scroll to the product name, it go a bit far than expected
[image: like this, even I put a ref div on top of the series name]

And another problem is, when first landing on the page, the scroll function doesn’t work at first. I have to re-select the brand then select the product in order to make the scroll function work.

this is the old handleSearch

```
  const handleSearch = () => {
    setSearchClicked(true)

    if (!selectedBrand) {
      alert('Please select a brand')
      return
    }

    const selectedBrandData = films.find((film: any) => film.brand === selectedBrand)

    // Show all series of the selected brand
    const allSeriesData = selectedBrandData.series
    const allSeriesNames = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.series)
    const allSeriesDescs = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.desc)
    const allSeriesPics = allSeriesData.map((series: any) => series.product)

    setShowingProduct(allSeriesPics)
    setSelectedSeriesName(allSeriesNames)
    setSelectedSeriesDesc(allSeriesDescs)

    if (selectedSeries) {
      const index = allSeriesNames.indexOf(selectedSeries)
      if (index !== -1 && seriesRefs.current[index]) {
        window.scrollTo({
          top: seriesRefs.current[index].offsetTop,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the old search result

```
 {selectedSeriesName.map((seriesName, index) => (
            <div key={index} ref={(ref) => (seriesRefs.current[index] = ref)} className="mb-[70px] ">
              <p className={`${classes.brandName} text-center`}>{seriesName}</p>
              <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-5 lg:grid-cols-4 grid-cols-2 items-center xl:gap-7 gap-5 gap-x-7 justify-items-center mt-[57px] mb-[57px] ">
                {showingProduct[index].map((product: any) => (
                  <div
                    key={product.id}
                    className="md:w-[200px] md:h-[270px] h-[260px] hover:cursor-pointer "
                    onClick={() => {
                      setSelectedImage(product.pic)
                      setDetaila(product.a)
                      setDetailb(product.b)
                      setDetailc(product.c)
                      setDetaild(product.d)
                      setDetaile(product.e)
                      setDetailf(product.f)
                    }}
                  >
                    <img src={product.pic} className="aspect-square xl:h-[200px] lg:h-[180px]" />
                    <div className="mt-2 text-[18px]">
                      <p>
                        {product.name} {product.color}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
              <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: selectedSeriesDesc[index] }}
                className={`${classes.brandDesc} mt-[30px]`}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
```

as you can see, i put the ref above the series name

```
  <div key={index} ref={(ref) => (seriesRefs.current[index] = ref)} className="mb-[70px] ">
              <p className={`${classes.brandName} text-center`}>{seriesName}</p>
```